# Add space before each Capitalized word (minus the 1st one) using Scala code

Tags: regex, string, scala, string-matching, uppercase

I'm new to `Scala`... so far I'm really liking it. :)

Right now I'm playing with [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) and I'm amazed by how straightforward it is to get going.

Well... the problem at hand is that I'd like to make a string as the following one more readable:

```
UsersGroupedByRegistrationMonthYear.csv
```

The output should be:

```
Users Grouped By Registration Month Year.csv
```

Can you lend a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not regex, but a pretty straight forward approach.

```
val str = "UsersGroupedByRegistrationMonthYear.csv"
str.flatMap(c => if (c.isUpper) Seq(' ', c) else Seq(c)).trim
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this regex with 2 capturing groups:

```
([a-z0-9])([A-Z])
```

and replace using this pattern:

```
$1 $2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/4)

**Code:**

```
repl = input.replaceAll("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use String.split with regex lookarounds to tokenize your string by caps without throwing them away and then to combine tokens back into a string with spaces between tokens:

```
val in = "UsersGroupedByRegistrationMonthYear.csv"
val out = in.split("(?=[A-Z])").mkString(" ")

println("\"%s\"\nbecomes\n\"%s\"".format(in, out))
```

This yields:

```
"UsersGroupedByRegistrationMonthYear.csv"
becomes
"Users Grouped By Registration Month Year.csv"
```